# How to architect a flutter app that submits lot of form data to backend API

Tags: mobile, flutter, architecture

I am currently building a Flutter App for both iOS and Android and the purpose of the app is to collect data from user via lots of forms and then submit it to a backend endpoint.
I need to consider number of things:

1. User completes half of the form(s) and wants to save locally but submit it later
2. User submits the form but gets network error so data should not be lost
3. user submits successfully. at this point data should be either deleted from local storage or be kept and later should get sync with backend db.

Technical points

1. I may need to use local db. What's the best approach for it?
2. Maintain global state until data is either stored or sent

I would like to reach out to stack overflow community where collegues may have run into similar situation and can give me some ideas/hints on how best I can architect the app. And What are the libraries / pub packages I can use.

I need to use Flutter only.

Answer (score 1):

for storing the to be submitted data you might be looking for the shared preferences plugin. this lets you store data locally on the phone and lets you edit and delete this when the sync has been completed.

Comment: thanks! do you also recommend any particular library for beautiful forms? and what's your best way to maintain a state. i am coming from react background so leaning towards redux.